# Best method to stream results from web service

Tags: go

I'm currently writing against an xml service in which batched results are returned. I currently have the following:

```
type QueryEnvelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name   `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Envelope"`
    Body    *QueryBody `xml:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Body"`
}

type QueryBody struct {
    QueryResult *QueryResult `xml:"queryResponse>result"`
}

type QueryResult struct {
    QueryLocator QueryLocator `xml:"queryLocator"`
    Done         bool         `xml:"done"`
    Size         int          `xml:"size"`
    Records      interface{}  `xml:"records"`
}

type QueryLocator string

func (r *Resource) Query(sql string, r interface{}) error {
     // builds xml request
     // sends xml request through Resource which contains the net client
     // decodes the result into r (type for records in QueryResult)
}

func (r *Resource) QueryMore(q QueryLocator, r interface{}) error {
     // same as above except takes queryLocator and makes call to different endpoint in order to continue retrieving results, when QueryResult.Done == true, done fetching results
}
```

Obviously this needs refactored since the Client needs to see whether Done == true so they can continue to fetch. I was thinking of adding the following the following, and moving Query and QueryMore to be a method of Querier:

type Querier struct {
     r *Resource
     Done bool
     QueryLocator QueryLocator
}

func New(r *Resource) *Querier {}

Client side would then behave as such:

```
err := q.Query("sql statement", r)
if err != nil {
     // handle
}
// do stuff with r
for q.Done == false {
     q.QueryMore(r)
     // do stuff with r
}
```

I'm wondering what the idiomatic approach would be here in order to best "stream" the results.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You say you want a "stream", or do you just want to iterate over results? What's wrong with the iteration method you're proposing here?

Comment: I don't like that I have to handle the result of Query() and then handle it again within a loop of QueryMore(). I feel like there may be a more idiomatic way to set up the API

Comment: You mention SQL in your example, but I don't see any sql-like code. Have you tried the iteration patterns used by the sql package, or other database drivers?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I am writing against a soap service, not creating one. I do not have access to the sql server.

Comment: regardless, I'm referring to the patterns used by the drivers. I'll put something in an answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the pattern the stdlib [`sql`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql) package uses to iterate over rows. This way you can unify the initial query with subsequent calls.

There's a `Next()` method, which populates the internal structure with the query results, and returns `true` if there's a result pending. In your case, you would still need an initial constructor, like `Query`, but that would just setup the data-structure. Calling `Next()` does the real work, and calling `Scan(r)` (or whatever you'd like to call reading the result) just presents to result. Once iteration is done, you have an `Err()` method to check for any operational errors.

Altering the example from the sql package a bit:

```
// setup the query, but delay any action until we start iterating.
query, err := NewQuery(queryParameters)
// check err of course
defer query.Close()

for query.Next() {
    err = query.Scan(&r)
    ...
}
err = query.Err() // get any error encountered during iteration
```

You can also check out other drivers like [`mgo`](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo) for variations on this pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will be looking in to this later today or tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to refactor everything so that NewQuery() initiated a new Querier, and Next() was used for the entire iteration. Query and QueryMore became private. Thanks again